# Optimization of the exponential of the decision variable $x$

Tags: optimization, exponential-function, partial-derivative, exponentiation, lagrange-multiplier

The minima or maxima of optimization problems are typically derived by differentiating the Lagrangean of the objective function w.r.t. the decision variable $x$ being solved for.

Are there any optimization models in any field that contain in their objective function the exponential, $e^{f(x)}$, of the decision variable $x$?

I ask because the first derivative of $e^{x^2}$ for example is $2xe^{x^2}$, meaning the decision variable's presence becomes multiplicitous because of $e$'s chain rule, therefore making it difficult to isolate the decision variable from the Lagrangean first order conditions.

Any examples will do

Comment: "The minima or maxima of optimization problems are typically derived by differentiating the Lagrangean of the objective function w.r.t. the decision variable being solved for." That might be how problems have been typically solved so far in your textbooks and courses. In real life, most problems are solved by running numerical optimization solvers, because there are no closed-form solutions to first order conditions (KKT). Exponentials occur frequently in such problems

Comment: what are some examples of models whose objective function has an exponential

Comment: entropy optimization

Comment: do you know of any others?

Comment: Look up "exponential cone". Everything in a constraint can be used in an objective function.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "optimization model".  Do you mean an optimization problem (like fitting parameters of a model to data for "best fit"), or do you mean solution techniques that are specialized for (say) exponential dependencies?

Comment: example problems from any field

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks, I came across the following that shows KL-divergence can be transformed to an exponential function. What are some good starting references for exponential cone optimization? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677693/kullback-leibler-divergence-as-exponential-cone

Comment: https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/expo.html . Also, https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf is helpful for understanding.. BTW, eexponential cones are now available in Mosek - they weren't when that answer was written (by a Mosek employee). Now easy to do using CVX 2.2 + Mosek 9.x.

Comment: Converting KL-divergence to exponential cone allows for more reliable and efficient conic optimization solver, such as Mosek, to be applied, rather than general purpose nonlinear optimizer. You also don't need to supply or worry about derivatives. The solver takes care of all that.